# How to display axios payload with InnerHTML or createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, ecmascript-6, axios

I am writing just an inline script in an HTML page where I make an axios call and get back a JSON payload.  I want to then take the results from the async/await call and pass off the data to a setResults() function and display to the screen. All wanted to render any error back from the call into a setError() function to display. Could be possibly better using createElement?  Not sure how to deliver the data into the function and render as HTML? Any hints?

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.testResults = document.getElementsByClassName('test-results');
  }

  async run() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), '[Test]', 'Running the test');

    // TODO: Make the API call and handle the results
    const API_URL       = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
    const API_KEY       = 'c75f89dee2df592ecb5f3386294f4add';
    const LOCATION_CODE = '4608408';  // Brentwood Bonus!
    const FULL_API_URL  = `${API_URL}?id=${LOCATION_CODE}&appid=${API_KEY}`;

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(FULL_API_URL);
      console.log(response);
      // get response data and pass it to setResults() to be rendered
     } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // if error pass it to setError() and render
     }
   }

   setError(message) {
     // TODO: Format the error
     this.testResults.innerHTML = (message || '').toString();
   }

   setResults(results) {
     // Get the results from the Axios call and render as HTML on page
     this.testResults.innerHTML = (results || '').toString();
   }
}
```

The data returned is in JSON, so InnerHTML isn't really the answer. Here is the sample weather data structure that is returned.

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -86.7828,
        "lat": 36.0331
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 803,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "broken clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 290.49,
        "feels_like": 289.87,
        "temp_min": 287.86,
        "temp_max": 292.76,
        "pressure": 1010,
        "humidity": 61
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 7.2,
        "deg": 270
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 75
    },
    "dt": 1697301531,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 2006753,
        "country": "US",
        "sunrise": 1697284359,
        "sunset": 1697325201
    },
    "timezone": -18000,
    "id": 4608408,
    "name": "Brentwood",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: template strings are nice: `this.testResults.innerHTML =\`total: ${results.total} <b>${results.items.length} items</b> \``

Comment: templates + innerHTML is fine if the result display is non-interactive. if there are form controls or state (like pagination), use a vdom or mvc framework.

Comment: If you get back JSON data, then `innerHTML` is no good. Yes, use `createElement` and `textContent` (or even `createTextNode`), but if you don't show us *what* data you get back and *how* you want to render it, we cannot help you further. Please [edit] your question to add these details.

Comment: Thanks all.  I edited my question to include some of the sample weather data in JSON resturned.  I am thinking I will need to know how to pass the data from the axios function into setResults() and then maybe i need a combination of map() and createElement to render to the page?

Comment: To pass the data to `setResults`, simply call `this.setResults(response.data);` where you currently have your comment about doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now which parts of this JSON data do you want to render, in what elements, how do you want them to look like? What should the resulting DOM/HTML be?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Bergi.  Something maybe as a table would be cool?  Perhaps the parent nodes of the Json be table headings, and then the other values as <tr>'s and <td's>, or even something like <section> or <aside> to break up the parent/child relationship?  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @Rachel Yes, that's a good idea. Please try something, and [edit] the question to show us your attempt if it doesn't work! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement for some examples